# Permissions for listing virtual machines with Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, virtual-machine, azure-rest-api

I am trying to use the request:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?api-version=2020-12-01
```

From microsoft graph API:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#code-try-0.

I created an app registration within the an AD subscription. When I try to use the oauth2 credentials associated with the app registration I receive a 401. I believe this is due to a permissions error. I tried using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, but I am unable to assume the app registration to simulate the request. Any insight as to why this might be happening or how to debug the issue would be very helpful

Comment: The above call is not Graph API, rather its Azure REST API. HTTP 401 is permissions related error. Check your token in https://jwt.ms and see the logged on user has necessary permissions or not. If not provide necssary scopes/permissions/roles and retry. It will work.

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Hi, Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not a lack of permissions but the use of the wrong `scope`.

The error is actually very simple, you need to grant `Azure Service Management` api permissions instead of `MS graph` permissions, and then you need to set the `scope` to: `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`.

[image]

[image]

Next, use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token.

1. Request an authorization code in the browser.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

2. Redeem token.

[image]

Call api:

[image]

Please note that do not use [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) test, because you are not calling MS graph api, you can use postman.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the accepted answer, I had to set the scope to access this url...

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2020-12-01`

to:

`https://management.azure.com/.default`